# Getting the error : if: Expression Syntax

Tags: linux, bash, sed

My snippet :

```bash
if  [[ $1 =~ .*core.* ]] &&  [[ $3 =~ .*165.* ]] ;
then 
{
sed -ie "s?parameter PRTIME .*?#parameter PRTIME \nparameter PRTIME = 3.300000;?g" $1_chain.v 
}
elif [[ $1 =~ .*top.* ]] &&  [[ $3 =~ .*ss.* ]] ;
then

{
sed -ie "s?parameter PRTIME .*?#parameter PRTIME \nparameter PRTIME = 3.000000;?g" $1_chain.v 
}
else
{ 
sed -ie "s?parameter PRTIME .*?#parameter PRTIME \nparameter PRTIME = 2.500000;?g" $1_chain.v 
}
fi
```

When the input1 from user has a string matching core and input3 user input has a string matching ss then the given command needs to be executed in the specified file .

Comment: I don't see any indication, that the script is being executed by bash. At the very least, put a `echo $BASH_VERSION` before the firts ìf` and tell us which version is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if  [[ $1 =~ .*core.* ]] && [[ $3 =~ .*165.* ]]
then 
    sed -ie "s?parameter PRTIME .*?#parameter PRTIME \nparameter PRTIME = 3.300000;?g" "$1_chain.v"
elif [[ $1 =~ .*top.* ]] && [[ $3 =~ .*ss.* ]]
then
    sed -ie "s?parameter PRTIME .*?#parameter PRTIME \nparameter PRTIME = 3.000000;?g" "$1_chain.v"
else
    sed -ie "s?parameter PRTIME .*?#parameter PRTIME \nparameter PRTIME = 2.500000;?g" "$1_chain.v"
fi
```

I did not try or validate your `sed` command, since you did not provide a complete sample data set.

For syntax, you can put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/